# Variable that depends on another variable VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an interesting question about referencing another variable based on another variable in an array.

Below is my code:

Dim company, price, sdev, mean, random

```
Dim companies
companies = Array("mm", "tgt", "boog")

mm_price = 0
mm_mean = 0
mm_sdev = 0

tgt_price = 0
tgt_mean = 0
tgt_sdev = 0

boog_price = 0
boog_mean = 0
boog_sdev = 0

For i = 1 To 3
    company = companies(i)
    mean = company & "_mean"
    sdev = company & "_sdev"

Next i
```

Now, the issue occurs when I attempt to define the "mean" and "sdev" variables, as they will not use the "0" value, but instead give it the string name "mm_mean" etc. mm_mean = 0, therefore, I want mean = 0 when i = 1. Clear?

Thanks, and let me know. It is a rather strange question, and the code is cut from many different functions, so if it doesn't make sense as to *why* I am doing this, my apologies.  I tried to make it as simple as possible so it wouldn't confuse the answerer.

Comment: VBA does not support "metaprogramming" like this (VBS has `Eval`/`Execute`, but VBA does not), so you cannot reference another variable by its string name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good example of when custom data-structures (aka "record types", "structs") should be used to group related data together. In VBA the syntax is `Type`:

```
Type Company
    Name As String
    Price As Currency
    Mean As Double
    SDev As Double
End Type

Public Sub CalculateCompanyInfo()

    Dim companies(3) As Company
    companies(0).Name = "mm"
    companies(0).Price = 123

    companies(1).Name = "tgt"
    companies(1).Price = 456

    companies(2).Name = "boog"
    companies(2).Price = 789

    For i As Integer = 0 to UBound(companies)
        companies(i).Mean = ...
        companies(i).SDev = ...
    Next i

End Sub
```

Where `...` means whatever custom calculation you need to do to get that value.

Comment: Was going to suggest a class module, but this will do =)

Comment: FYI - You have used `Dim companies(3) As Company` but then only populated 3 of the 4 array elements with data for the `Name` and `Price` fields, but looped to process all 4 array elements.  Did you mean your example to use `Dim companies(2) As Company` instead, so that it only ranged from `0 To 2`?